# line.startsWith does not interprete the string

Tags: java

I am trying to not print lines start with string like `2 2` but with the current state just line starts with `notice` are being delteted. I debugged it and wrote the Output in the code lines. How can I fix it?

I appreciate any help.

**Code:**

```
    int number = Character.getNumericValue(newName.charAt(2));
    //here start_zero is `2 2`
    String start_zero = new StringBuilder().append(number)
            .append(" ").append(number).toString();

    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path + File.separator
            + newName);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                            //here is the first line `2 2`
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
//here is start_zero `2 2` too.
            if (!line.startsWith("notice") || !line.startsWith(start_zero) ) {

                writer.println(line);
                writer.flush();
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem - it's really hard to understand your question at the moment. I strongly suspect you just want to change your `||` to `&&` though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!line.startsWith("notice") || !line.startsWith(start_zero) ) {

                writer.println(line);
                writer.flush();
            }
```

your problem is in your if statement. You used OR, but you should have used AND

```
if (!line.startsWith("notice") && !line.startsWith(start_zero) ) {

                writer.println(line);
                writer.flush();
            }
```

if the first returns true ... which is your case, the second doesn't matter anymore in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your if statement operator from OR to AND like this

```
if (!line.startsWith("notice") && !line.startsWith(start_zero) )
                   {rest of code here}
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition:

```
if (!line.startsWith("notice") || !line.startsWith(start_zero) )
```

Means: "Do the following if the line doesn't start with "notice" or if the line doesn't start with "2 2".

It means that if the line doesn't start with "notice", the whole condition becomes true. Because it's correct to say that the first or the second conditions were met when just one of them is met.

If you want to print the line only if it neither starts with "notice" nor with "2 2", you have to use one of these conditions:

```
! ( line.startsWith("notice") || line.startsWith(start_zero) )
```

(Note: **the parentheses are important**.) Or the equivalent (by DeMorgan's law):

```
! line.startsWith("notice") && ! line.startsWith(start_zero)
```

The first can be interpreted as 'Do the following if it's not true that the line starts with either "notice" or "2 2"', and the second as 'Do the following if the line both doesn't start with "notice" and doesn't start with "2 2"'.